# jquery map and web site language selection

Tags: jquery, dictionary

i am building multilanguage site. In home page i'm using jquery map from http://jqvmap.com/

I want that selected country to be with different color.

Maybe someone was using this amazing map plugin and can help? Thank you!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
map: 'europe_en',
backgroundColor: null,
borderColor: '#818181',
borderOpacity: 0.25,
borderWidth: 1,
color: '#ffffff',
hoverColor: '#f69338',
hoverOpacity: null,
enableZoom: false,
normalizeFunction: 'linear',
scaleColors: ['#b6d6ff', '#005ace'],
selectedColor: '#f69338',
selectedRegions: '',
showTooltip: true,
onRegionClick: function(element, code, region)
{

    if (code == 'de')
    {
    location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.com/de/"
    }
}
    });
});
```

I found a solution on how to detect language, but don't know how to select country by current language in map.

```
if ( document.location.href.indexOf('de') > -1 ) {
         // than select country in map
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com). Its API has `selectedRegions` parameter to set the regions which are selected initially.